# Substr Method in PHP is returning a string at the wrong position

Tags: php, substr

$result is a string defined above this code containing the html of a website, it is a very long string.

```
<?php
    $url = "http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=sr_pg_1?me=A34JWT04R7KMFW&rh=i%3Amerchant-items%2Cn%3A%21493964&ie=UTF8&qid=1435757351";
    $ch=curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    $needle = 'id="result_0"';
    $position = strpos($result, $needle);
    $pos2 = ($position + 12);
    echo substr($result,$pos2,8);
?>
```

The code returns the string at $position, and not $pos2.  when i echo out $pos2 i get the correct number.

Comment: Please post complete code blocks

Comment: @AbraCadaver I guess we can play poker now :) Everyone can guess what's in: `$result`.

Comment: @AbraCadaver sorry i added it. please help if you can.

Answer (score 1):

check first the $position

```
var_dump($position);
die();
```

if is not what you need, change $needle string